# Can we send objects when routing in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I was trying to pass objects when the route changes in Angular 4. Basically, I was trying to mimic something that could be achieved using an UI Router in Angular JS. My previous app used routing and navigation using UI Router module for Angular JS.

There I was able to route to a URL by providing a state and with that an object using the `$state.go()` method.

The object that was passed to the route could be retrieved using the $stateParams and can be used in the Controller for that route. Achieving this functionality with Angular 4 default router, I believe is not possible.

Is there a way by which objects can be passed around when routing in Angular 4 and those objects can be retrieved by the activated component.

Will not the shared service lose its data when the page is hard refreshed by the user? Also, what are your thoughts on using UI Router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think passing an Object on routing is a quiet a bad idea.

I'm using "shared-services" to pass Objects from one Component to another on routing.

For example build an Share-Service with getter and setter for that object and set it when you route to the new Component and get it from that service when the new Component is initialized.

That Service should be provided in the parent module in which those two Components are.

Comment: Will not the shared service lose its data when the page is refreshed?

Comment: yes the data would be lost. If thats necessary you could think about saving it to localstorage.

Comment: Yes i think so too. Can you pls upvote the question because a lot of research has gone into it and someone has down voted the question for unknown reasons.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular Router 7.2 you can send it as NavigationExtras and retrieve it from the window history.

```
this.router.navigate(['/foo'], {state: {bar: {...}}});
```

or even

```
<a [routerLink]=”/foo” [state]=”{ bar: {...}}”>Foo</a>
```

you can then get the data in when navigation finishes from the history object

```
history.state.bar
```

Whether this is a good idea, I cannot say but
see https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255
and https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state

for more information.